# Cant make font-weight lighter (monsterrat)

Tags: css, fonts

I want to use Montserrat with a font-weight of 200 exactly like they have on the image text on this website: http://www.cohabs.com/

I have the font working using this method

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
```

and

```
h1 {
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-weight: 200;
}
```

But the font weight can only be regular or bold according to [google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat), so where/how did that website use it with a font-weight of 200?

Comment: font-weight is 300 in that site.

Comment: [hero-content] .lead {
    font-weight: 200;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like they are loading font from their server

go to their `main.css` and ctrl+f `url(../assets/fonts/montserrat-light.woff)` u'll see ur self

you can find same font [here](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/montserrat), u can also load it from ur server if needed

to use any font which u want to host on server, u need to download that font and host it to ur server I suggest to place them in `fonts` folder and refer below code

you can replace `lovelyFont` with ur own font name

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'lovelyFont';
    src: url(../'fonts/lovely_font.eot'); 
    src: 
        local('lovelyFont'),
        local('lovelyFont'),
        url('fonts/lovelyFont.otf') 
        format('opentype');
}

div { font-family: 'lovelyFont', sans-serif; }
```

for more details refer [this](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/01/how-to-use-any-font-you-like-with-css3/) or [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) links

Comment: I downloaded the monsterrat zip file but i dont know how to actually use the fonts, cant find any help either.

Answer (score 2):

Montserrat light version isn't available on Google Fonts.
Google Fonts only has 'Regular' and 'Bold' version of Montserrat.

You can download more Montserrat types here: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/montserrat

Answer (score 0):

They are using Montserrat Hairline font for the thin letters.